# Assigning symbol and colour to attributes using Arcade expression and ArcGIS Online

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, color, arcade

I would like to use an Arcade expression in ArcGIS Online web maps to assign a symbol and a colour to different attributes. For example, if the attribute value is 'yes': the symbol is round and has a green colour. And if the attribute value is 'no': Symbol is a square and has a red colour.

Is this possible in an Arcade expression?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible!!

I am sharing the workflow to be followed.

Here, I have demonstrated if StreetType is "ST" symbolize as "Green Circle" and if the StreetType is "DR" symbolize them as "Red Squares"

[image]

Use the below Arcqade Expression to set up the service.

```
var PCI = $feature.StreetType;
if (PCI == "ST") {
    return "Yes";
} else if (PCI == "DR") {
    return "No";
}
```

Once the expression is set, select the option to symbolize
[image]

Set the shape and color as per your requirements.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it true that if an attribute has more values than 'yes' and 'no' it would not be possible ( for instance an extra attribute value of 'maybe')? And I can not set the symbol from the expression right?

Comment: You can add the "Maybe" and set the symbology as well, just that you have to modify the expression by using the Multiple IIF() statements.