# Returning top three highest numeric values using Arcade

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I was introduced to Arcade a year or so ago and haven't implemented it into any of my projects as I hadn't had a need to, but I think I might have a use for it, if it can work.

I have a feature class that summarizes all of our mosquito trap data for our season. And in this dataset we have roughly 30 types of mosquitoes we catch throughout the season.  I wanted to create a pop up that only shows the top 3 mosquito species (in terms of amount caught) for that particular trap.

Is this possible?

Before I research this any further I'd figure I'd ask the pros!

Comment: You had a tag for ArcGIS 10.0 but Arcade did not exist until long after that version and so I removed it.

Comment: Kindly check this, something similar https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379528/assigning-symbol-and-colour-to-attributes-using-arcade-expression-and-arcgis-onl/379590#379590

Comment: This will depend on how your data is structured. Is it a single feature class with fields for each type of mosquito, related tables or something else? Arcade provides an OrderBy function.